# Lyx does not allow paste double quotes (U+022) in ERT boxes

Tags: lyx

**Background:**

Now I cannot paste in a ERT box some as simple as `"a"` (with the  U+0022 quotes). And yes, I need just paste `"a"`, not ``` ``a'', ``` nor `«a»`, nor `\gl a \gr` nor ... The quotes are not for plain text or verbatim environments, but for R code in knitr documents.

Seem that this is not a bug, but an [delivered restriction](https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-cvs@lists.lyx.org/msg17031.html) to prevent paste uncodable characters into verbatim. That could be useful to avoid "nearly malware" characters as the detestable zero width space, but for me, the new feature is proving to be extremely annoying, because everytime I try to paste something as common as `"` in a ERTbox,  (a) LyX open a window with a error message:

> Uncodable content
>   The characters "" are uncodable in this verbatim context and thus have not been pasted.

...and worse (b), once you close this window, LyX paste a mutiled version of the clipboard.  It could be hard of repair in a long code and probably it will produce a fatal error (no pdf) if you failed to restore some of the deleted characters.

It happens also if the encoding is not the default latin1 but  utf8. 
Funnily, LyX really cannot prevent paste u+022 when copied from an external program (but it bothers you with error message anyway).

**MWE:**

In LyX 2.3, open a new document, open a ERT box (Ctrl+L), just wite `"a"` inside it (with the quotes, of course), copy it and paste in the same box.

And the question is:

**How disable this "feature"?**  Otherwise, there is some workaround for safely pasting in ERT boxes?

**Solution**

Strangely, the "PPA stable" (nor the PPA daily) do not have any package with the stable  version cited by  @TorbjørnT. ( 2.3.0 February 24 2018), so, as far I can see ,there not are available binaries for the stable version from here, and my distro want to install the older 2.2 version.

But luckily the sources of [lyx-2.3.0.tar.gz](https://ftp.lip6.fr/pub/lyx/stable/2.3.x/lyx-2.3.0.tar.gz) have the right versión. Compiling it slow and boring but works, and it is relatively easy. Briefly, as root (you know ... safer as normal user adding `sudo`!):

1. `# apt-get build-dep lyx`
2. `# wget https://ftp.lip6.fr/pub/lyx/stable/2.3.x/lyx-2.3.0.tar.gz`
3. `# tar xzvf lyx-2.3.0.tar.gz`
4. `# cd lyx-2.3.0/`
5. `# ./configure`
6. `# make install`

The lyx now will manage correctly the quoted text. ;)

Comment: I can't reproduce this (LyX 2.3.0 on Kubuntu), copy-pasting `"a"` works fine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Is your version from the official .deb package?  My version is exactly 2.3.0rc2 (Sunday, January 28, 2018) with Qt Version 4.8.7 in Linux Mint, downloaded  from the PPA recommended in the LyX page.

Comment: A release candidate is not necessarily a "finished" product, I'd first try getting the final release. I probably used the PPA mentioned on LyX.org, but I can't actually remember. In Help -> About LyX it says "LyX Version 2.3.0 (Saturday, February  24, 2018)".

Comment: What happens if you escape the quote? `\"a\"`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thar is pasted only ` \a\ `

Comment: Odd. I don't have lyx and can't test. But it sounds as if you should  make a bug report.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about a bug that is solved updating to the stable version.

Comment: @Fran You found the same regression as reported [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=mid&q=20180216212434.vocare25qvrqfh6t%40Opti1604), and fixed [here](https://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/8f9b733e/lyxgit). As for the PPA issue, see [here](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11166).